# SVN commit takes too long

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, subversion

I'm using my Raspberry Pi 2 as a local SVN server, but when I try to commit a whole new project (more than 3000 files) it takes too long for commit. There are only appearing a few dots per hour in the last case with more than 6k files.

**Configuration of the Raspberry Pi:** [Here](https://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-how-to-svn-server/) is more information on how is set up my SVN server with a few changes. There is a trunk folder and it is working only with HTTPS. Also the microSD card of the Raspberry Pi is Class 10 with writing speed up to 48 MB/s.

**Network configuration:** My computer and the Raspberry Pi are on the same network. My computer's IP address is 192.168.0.100, the Raspberry Pi's IP address is 192.168.0.200 and port 443 of my public IP address is forwarded to the Raspberry Pi, and I make commits to my public IP address which is set to a subdomain of one of my domains.

So my questions are:

- Is there a problem with protocols, and is it related with commit speed?
- Is it a network problem? Should I commit to local IP address of the Raspberry Pi?
- Is it a problem that the SVN server version is 1.7.5, but on my commit machine the SVN version is 1.8.13?
- How do I check where the problem is, because at this moment I don't know how to do it and I don't know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Which filesystem are you using on the RPi2, do you have a swap file and what is the swappiness set to? It is likely to be a problem with using different versions of subversion, yes.

Comment: You can get general I/O stats with [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) and check whether a program is blocked on I/O syscall with something like `ps -Ao stat,fname | grep D`.

Comment: Everything with I/O was fine, because speed of the cart.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced performance problems with different versions of subversion on the client and server in the past. I think this could be the problem.

Comment: I've try to fix this problem few times. Finally I realize that SVN is not the perfect solution and now I'm using GIT and everything is a "good song" for now :)